# Will VM protocol support two JVMs?

Tags: java, jvm, activemq-classic

I would like to run `activemq` broker on `vm://` protocol as a standalone application and send messages to it's queue from a program that resides in different JVM instance. Is it possible? Will it work?

[This Documentation](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.0/connectivity_guide/N050FA630.09E1EB28.html) clearly states that:

> "inside the same JVM to communicate with each other inside the JVM"

but that doesn't make sense to me at all :) The scenario where we have external JMS broker (on the same machine) and clients running in different JVMs (like Tomcat, for instance) is not that uncommon. Active-MQ documentation doesn't help me at all, since they probably assumed that solution to my question is obvious, thus my confusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Just use a different protocol that supports networking, the documentation lists three of them. The `vm://` protocol isn't the one appropriate for your given use case.

Comment: Well, it didn't make that much sense to me not to state that clearly in the documentation of ActiveMq. I ended up looking for that info on some totally unrelated site, so I guess that's why I was lost.

Which other transports you have in mind? Sorry, I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: It seems like the ActiveMq model is to have only API documentation and sell books by the authors as the primary in-depth reference. You might want to badger your employer to buy the book if you're going to be using ActiveMq. The other protocols are on the same site you linked to: [OpenWire](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/connectivity_guide/FMBConnectOpenwireIntro.html) (the default), [Stomp](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/connectivity_guide/FMBConnectivityStompIntro.html) and [REST](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/connectivity_guide/FMBConnectRestIntro.html)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to write some test case to prove if it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the following setup:

1. Standalone ActiveMQ broker
2. Simple Java producer-consumer program ran in separate JVM

Both of them were using `vm://test` broker.

**Conclusions**

Id didn't matter whether or not ActiveMQ broker was running. In both cases my simple example ran smoothly - it was creating VM broker, which has been discarded when the JVM was shut down along with my program.

This means, that truly VM brokers are running in just one JVM and the cannot be accessed from other JVM, at least with the simplest config.